# Strategy game timed resources

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, when a user registers, instead of starting with 0 Wood, 0 Stone, 0 Gold they start with timestamps as their Wood, Stone and Gold (Number like 1375674873). Where is my error?

```
$timeNow = time();
$timeExpire = $timeNow - 2;
$User = $con->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
$UserInfo = $User->fetch_object();

$con->query("UPDATE players SET Time='$timeNow' WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");
$con->query("UPDATE players SET TimeExpire='$timeExpire' WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");

if(time() >= $UserInfo->TimeExpire) {

    $getAmount = time() - $UserInfo->TimeExpire;
    echo $getAmount;
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood=Wood+$getAmount WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Stone=Stone+$getAmount WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Gold=Gold+$getAmount WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");

}
```

With **$getAmount** I'm calculating how many expirations there were. So even if the user is logged off, when they log back in after 2 hours they will still get the money for that period of time.

Comment: `$getAmount = time() - $UserInfo->TimeExpire;` assigns today's time stamp minus some value.

Comment: `UPDATE players SET Time='$timeNow'` - If I read this right, you've now set the `Time` column in every row of the table to `$timeNow`?  (And not just your `player` as I'm guessing you intended)  To do what you wanted, you should add ` where Username='".$_SESSION['Username']'"`

Comment: I missed a WHERE. still, I dont think thats the problem. let me see

Comment: do you _really_ want to set time data and resources of _all_ players dependent on the apparently random one whose data is processed by your code ?

Comment: I addded the WHERE clause, but the problem with the timestap still persists  http://prntscr.com/1qn7v1

Comment: With `$getAmount` im calculating how many expirations were there. so even if the user is logged off, when they log back in after 2 hours they will get the money for that period of time

Answer (score 0):

If you go to a javascript console and run `new Date(1375674873)` it will give you this (if you're in EST):

`Fri Jan 16 1970 17:07:54 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

What that tells me is that when you create a new user in the database, the value they have for the `TimeExpire` column is not what you think it is. Check what the default value for the column is, and make sure that in your code, when you add a user to the database, you're manually setting their `TimeExpire` column to `time()` rather than relying on something automatic. If the database time doesn't exactly match the server time, then even using something like `now()` will not produce the correct number.

Also, as a sidenote, you can combine several of your queries as follows:

```
$con->query("UPDATE players SET Time='$timeNow', TimeExpire='$timeExpire' WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");
[...]
$con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood=Wood+$getAmount, Stone=Stone+$getAmount, Gold=Gold+$getAmount WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");
```

It's a little thing, but in general fewer queries means a faster website.